# Using mouse on Virtual Machine on Mac, but got keyboard signal

Tags: keyboard, vmware, virtualbox, driver

The question is, when I **press and move** my mouse in the virtual machine(such as choose many files), the machine seems to receive a signal of keyboard "C-press" and ""C-release", which means that when I finished the "press and move" operation, there seems like I type "c" on my keyboard after this operation(but I don't even connect a keyboard). I tried on Virtualbox windows VM and Ubuntu VM, also VMware remote VM, but all suffered this problem...

I think maybe there is something wrong with the driver, but that strange thing doesn't occur on my Mac host machine....So I'm really confused about that. And I didn't find similar problem as I suffered...Thanks for your solution or advice!

Here is an example below:

I don't know how to get a gif so there is a picture....when I press and drag some files in the directory, after that operation a "c“ was typed and the page jump to "search"...so I can't finish this work
[image]

**System version info:**

host OS: macOS 10.15.7

guest OS: every OS I tried suffered this problem, including:Windows10 and Ubuntu20 on Virtualbox, and those two on VMware remote server

Comment: And I just find double-click will lead to the same result....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What os type and version is the host OS and the guest OS? Narrowing down to one specific driver on both ends can sometimes be needed to troubleshoot this. (Be sure to edit the details into the body of the post so all can see the added details.)